# Group By : Spring JPA Specifications

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to use Spring Data JPA Specification and wanted to know how to use `Group By` in the Specifications. See below my current specs:

#### Repository

```
public interface OauthAccessTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<OauthAccessToken, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<OauthAccessToken> {
}
```

#### Specification

```
 public class OauthAccessTokenSpecification {

public static Specification<OauthAccessToken> equalsTokenId(final String tokenId) {
    return new Specification<OauthAccessToken>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OauthAccessToken> root,CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<OauthAccessToken>get("tokenId"), tokenId);
        }
    };
}



public static Specification<OauthAccessToken> equalsRefreshToken(final String refreshToken) {
    return new Specification<OauthAccessToken>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OauthAccessToken> root,CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<OauthAccessToken>get("refreshToken"), refreshToken);
        }
    };
}

public static Specification<OauthAccessToken> equalsAuthenticationId(final String authenticationId) {
    return new Specification<OauthAccessToken>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OauthAccessToken> root,CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<OauthAccessToken>get("authenticationId"), authenticationId);
        }
    };
}



public static Specification<OauthAccessToken> equalsClientId(final String clientId) {
    return new Specification<OauthAccessToken>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OauthAccessToken> root,CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<OauthAccessToken>get("clientId"), clientId);
        }
    };
}



public static Specification<OauthAccessToken> equalsUserName(final String userName) {
    return new Specification<OauthAccessToken>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<OauthAccessToken> root,CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<OauthAccessToken>get("userName"), userName);
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: maybe my topic can help you to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007656/using-group-by-with-specification-in-spring-data-count-method