# Specification and Group By

Tags: spring, jpa, nhibernate, criteria, specifications

I have a class that implements various Methods of Specification class. In a method it is called groupBy of "Criteria Query". But to call this specification in the repository of spring, generates the next error:

```
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [appServlet] en el contexto con ruta [/web_service] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] con causa raíz org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "analista0_.id_analista" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

And of SQL query is this:

```
select analista0_.id_analista as id56_, analista0_1_.apellido as apellido56_, analista0_1_.cedula as cedula56_, analista0_1_.id_ciudad as id10_56_, analista0_1_.correo as correo56_, analista0_1_.direccion as direccion56_, analista0_1_.estatus as estatus56_, analista0_1_.nombre as nombre56_, analista0_1_.telefono as telefono56_, analista0_1_.tipo_menu as tipo9_56_, analista0_.administrador as administ1_57_ from Analista analista0_ inner join persona analista0_1_ on analista0_.id_analista=analista0_1_.id left outer join requerimiento requerimie1_ on analista0_.id_analista=requerimie1_.id_analista where analista0_.administrador<>? and (requerimie1_.estatus in (? , ? , ? , ? , ?) or  not (exists (select requerimie2_.id_requerimiento from requerimiento requerimie2_ where analista0_.id_analista=requerimie2_.id_analista))) order by count(distinct requerimie1_.id_requerimiento) asc limit ?
```

Obviously, the error is for group by clausule.
In this case, how would implement the GROUP BY clause?

This specification class:

```js
public Specification<Analista> consultarCantRequerimientos(final List<String> estatus) {
  
  return new Specification<Analista>(){
          
   public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Analista> entity, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    
    inicializar(entity, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder);
    
    
    Map<String, JoinType> entidades=new HashMap<String, JoinType>();
    entidades.put("requerimientos", JoinType.LEFT);
    Map<String, Join<?,?>> joins = crearJoins(entidades);
    
    
    Expression<Long> cantRequerimientos = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(joins.get("requerimientos"));
    
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(new Selection[]{
      cantRequerimientos.alias("cantRequerimientos"),
      entity.get("id")
    });
    
    
    List<Predicate> restricciones = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    restricciones.add(
      criteriaBuilder.notEqual(entity.get("administrador"), true)
    );
    if(estatus!=null && !estatus.isEmpty())
     restricciones.add(
       criteriaBuilder.or(
         joins.get("requerimientos").get("estatus").in(estatus),
         criteriaBuilder.isEmpty(entity.<List<?>>get("requerimientos"))
         )
       );
    
    
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    orders.add(criteriaBuilder.asc(cantRequerimientos));
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);

     List<Expression<?>> groupBy = new ArrayList<Expression<?>>();
     groupBy.add(entity.get("id"));
     
     criteriaQuery.groupBy(groupBy);
              return criteriaBuilder.and(restricciones.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
   }
   
  };
```

Comment: Please share the code for the specification query

Comment: @ddsu I posted my code. Tanks.

Comment: maybe my solution can help you to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406923/group-by-spring-jpa-specifications

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer in this post, if you need:

http://codekea.com/EDlb6J4kbK0w/spring-data-jpa-specification-to-select-specific-columns.html

Comment: hey. I'm unable to visit the link that you've pasted in the answer. thanks